# Weak convergence and convergence of functionals in dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, dual-spaces, pointwise-convergence

Let $X$ be a normed space, $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X$ and $(x_n')_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X'$ such that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ weakly converges to $x \in X$ and $(x_n')_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges pointwise to $x'$. 
What can you say about the convergence of $x'(x_n)$?

If I had that $X$ is a Banach space, I could use that then $x' \in X'$ (as a pointwise limit of linear and bounded functionals) and hence by definition of the weak convergence of $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ we would receive that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x'(x_n)=x'(x)$. Is this right so far?

Now if I don't have that $X$ is Banach I'm wondering if I can show the same? 
I thought about something like this: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x'(x_n) =  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} x_m'(x_n) = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_m'(x_n) = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} x_m'(x) = x'(x)$$ . But I'm not sure how I can argue that the limits are interchanged. Would it suffice if the limit of $x'_n$ would be uniformly instead of pointwise?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ then any $x'\in X'$ satisfies $x'(x_n)\to x'(x)$

Comment: Is it obvious that $x'$ is in the dual space if $X$ is not Banach?

Comment: Ah your question was a bit unclear. So $x_n'\to x'\in X^{\sharp}$ but you are not assuming that this $x'$ is continuous? In which case the result is no, there will be discontinuous functionals $x'$ for which $x'(x_n)\not\to x'(x)$

Comment: Ah good to know! Sorry for being a bit unclear. This might stem from the fact that I just posed the question for myself while preparing for the exam.

Comment: If $\|x'_n-x'\|\to0$ in norm then $x'$ is continuous and you get the result. I'm not sure about the non-uniform case

Comment: There may be a counter example lurking here, but I don't study counter examples and am not well placed to help

Comment: I kept thinking about your claim that if $||x_n'-x'|| \rightarrow 0$ then the pointwise convergence of $(x_n')_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ to $x'$ suffices that $x'$ is continuous [being in a normed space]. Maybe I'm a bit blind... is the argument obvious?

Comment: Perhaps there is a more elementary proof for the case of linear functions $\psi:X\to\Bbb R$, but in general we have the "Banach-Saks-Steinhaus" theorem: If $X$ is a Banach space, $Y$ a normed linear space and $(T_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\subseteq\mathscr{L}(X,Y)$ a sequence which pointwise converges to a function $T:X\to Y$, then $T\in\mathscr{L}(X,Y)$ and $\|T\|\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\|T_n\|$. Set $Y=\Bbb R$ and $T_n:=x'_n$ and you obtain $x'$ is continuous and linear (and that $\|x'\|\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\|x'_n\|$)

Comment: The proof relies on the uniform boundedness principle, which itself relies on a corollary of the Baire Category Theorem. Not super complicated but not elementary or obvious

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! But in my case $X$ is just a normed space and not necessarily Banach, so I think using UBP won't work (this it what I thought of too when thinking about the case $X$ Banach)

Comment: Oh my, yes you're right, I keep forgetting that.

Comment: I apologise for my frazzled typings yesterday... but the answer is going to be: if $x'$ is discontinuous it is always possible that a weak-convergent sequence $x_n$ might not converge under $x'$, but if $x'$ is continuous then it is guaranteed

Comment: Thank you! So, basically what I tried to prove in the second part isn't even possible. I'm going to think of a counter example:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the set of all 1-periodic trigonometric polynomials $$X=\{\sum_{n\in F} c_ne^{2\pi in\cdot}: F\subset\mathbb{Z}\hspace{2mm}\textrm{finite}, c_n\in\mathbb{C} \} $$ with the norm $$\displaystyle \|p\| = \left(\int_0^1 |p(t)|^2\ dt\right)^{1/2}.$$ Let $x_n(t) = e^{2\pi i nt}$ and $$x_m'(p) = \sum_{k=-m}^m \int_0^1 p(t)e^{-2\pi ikt}\ dt.$$ Then, $x_n\to 0$ weakly and $x_m'\to x'$ pointwise on $X$, where $x'(p) = p(0)$ for all $p\in X$. We have
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}x_m'(x_n) = 0, \hspace{5mm} 
  \lim_{n\to\infty} x'(x_n) =
  \lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}x_m'(x_n) = 1$$

---

Note that $\|x_m'\|^2 = 2m+1$, so $(\|x_m'\|)$ is not a bounded sequence. Also $x'$ is not a bounded linear functional on $X$.

Lastly, aside from an individual example, the theorem below might come in handy to get a more general result, which is nothing more than a conclusion of the uniform boundedness theorem.

> **Theorem:** Let $Y,Z$ be a Banach spaces, $P_n:Y\to Z$ be bounded linear operators, $X$ be a dense subspace of $Y$. Suppose that the
> sequence $(P_na)$ converges in $Z$ for each $a\in X$. Then, the
> following are equivalent.
>
> i. $(P_na)$ converges in $Z$ for all $a\in Y$.
>
> ii. $\{P_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a uniformly bounded set of operators.

For your problem, just take $Y$ be the completion of $X$, $Z=\mathbb{C}$,  and $P_n = x_n'$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!